# Image size based on CGSizeMake(40, 40)

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I have this code, but I dont know how big I have to make the image to look good on Retina,none Retina and iPad.

```
MPHero *hero = [MPHero spriteNodeWithTexture:hero_texture size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
```

name.png - for none retina
name@2x.png - for retina
name~ipad.png
name@2x~ipad.png

But what this meean`CGSizeMake(40, 40)` , 40x40 pixels or 40x40 points

Comment: 40 points, when used in retina screens, implicitly means 80

Answer (score 0):

CGSizeMake(40, 40) guarantees that image will take 40x40 points on the screen, whether you use name.png or name@2x.png, so it means points that image will cover on the screen